# django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError REST API post request

Tags: python-3.x, post, request

Getting django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'email_id' while post request. Here's my code

views.py:

```
def post(self, request):
    video_file = self.request.data['media_file']
    user_email_id = self.request.data['email_id']

    file_storage = FileSystemStorage()
    saved_file_name = file_storage.save(str(uuid.uuid4()), video_file)
```

upload.py:

```
headers = {"Authorizarion": "auth/key"}
data = {"email_id": "email@email.com",
        "media_file": open(video.file_path, "rb")}
response = requests.post("/api/url", headers=headers, data=data)
```

When try to upload the file via Postman works fin as it takes care of Content-Type, but trying  to upload in the backend makes it difficult to clear it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you're not passing the `email_id` - can you print its value in `upload.py` before you post?

To be on the safe side, provide a default value in your `views.py`:

```
video_file = self.request.data.get("media_file", None)
user_email_id = self.request.data.get("email_id", None)
```

Replace `None` with whatever you want as a default if a field is missing.

**UPDATE**: Of course, then you'll encounter the issue of uploading file contents the way you do. To upload the actual file you should use a `files` structure in your `requests.post()` call, e.g.:

```
headers = {"Authorizarion": "auth/key"}
data = {"email_id": "email@email.com"}
files = {"media_file": open(video.file_path, "rb")}
response = requests.post("/api/url", headers=headers, data=data, files=files)
```

Then on Django side you'll have to retrieve the contents as:

```
def post(self, request):
    video_file = request.FILES.get('media_file', None)
    user_email_id = request.POST.get('email_id', None)
    # you should probably validate video_file and user_email_id here
    file_storage = FileSystemStorage()
    saved_file_name = file_storage.save(str(uuid.uui`d4()), video_file)
```